# LWJGL Lighting not working properly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, lighting, normals

I am trying to add lighting to my LWJGL engine in Java.
I used a heightmap of earth to render the terrain and I want to add a sun / lightsource but for some reason, probably because I messed something up the lighting won't work properly.

Here's a image of the map, I currently deleted the sea so the lighting is more clear.
(It's imgur because it says that I need 10 reputation to post images)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTPcE.jpg
The yellow thing is the light source. As you can see, there are two "shadow" lines coming out of the sides, I don't know why. My guess is that the normals are not correct.

Here's another image up close to the tiles, I use 2 triangles to render one pixel on the heightmap.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EX1O.jpg
You can see that one of the triangles does render "properly" but the other one doesn't, they are all the same greyish / green colour.

The code that loads the heightmap and creates an tiles[][] and a normal[][]:

```
public void createMap(File heightmap) {

    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(heightmap);
        tiles = new float[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
        normals = new Vector3f[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
        int rgb;

        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                rgb = image.getRGB(x, y);
                tiles[x][y] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;

            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < tiles.length - 1; x++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < tiles[x].length - 1; z++) {
            try {
                Vector3f p1 = new Vector3f(x, tiles[x][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                Vector3f p2 = new Vector3f(x, tiles[x][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                Vector3f p3 = new Vector3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                normals[x][z] = UtilMath.getNormal(p1, p2, p3);
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            try {
                Vector3f p1 = new Vector3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                Vector3f p2 = new Vector3f(x, tiles[x][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                Vector3f p3 = new Vector3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                normals[x+1][z+1] = UtilMath.getNormal(p1, p2, p3);
            } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

The method that creates the display list to render the map:

```
public void createDisplayList() {
    Random rand = new Random();

    int mapDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(mapDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);

    glPushMatrix();
    {

        for(int x = 0; x < tiles.length - 1; x++) {
            for(int z = 0; z < tiles[x].length - 1; z++) {
                glColor3f(0, 0.75f, 0);
                try {
                    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                    glNormal3f(normals[x][z].x, normals[x][z].y, normals[x][z].z);
                    glVertex3f(x, tiles[x][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                    glVertex3f(x, tiles[x][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                    glVertex3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                    glEnd();
                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                try {
                    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
                    glNormal3f(normals[x+1][z+1].x, normals[x+1][z+1].y, normals[x+1][z+1].z);
                    glVertex3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                    glVertex3f(x, tiles[x][z+1] * MODIFIER, z+1);
                    glVertex3f(x+1, tiles[x+1][z] * MODIFIER, z);
                    glEnd();
                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }

    }
    glPopMatrix();

    glEndList();
}
```

And finally, the method I use to calculate the normals:

```
public static Vector3f getNormal(Vector3f p1, Vector3f p2, Vector3f p3) {
    try {
        Vector3f normal = new Vector3f();

        Vector3f calU = new Vector3f(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y, p2.z - p1.z);
        Vector3f calV = new Vector3f(p3.x - p1.x, p3.y - p1.y, p3.z - p1.z);

        normal.setX(calU.y*calV.z - calU.z-calV.y);
        normal.setY(calU.z*calV.x - calU.x-calV.z);
        normal.setZ(calU.x*calV.y - calU.y-calV.x);

        return (Vector3f) normal.normalise();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know I have probably made a mistake with the normals.

I hope any of you know what I did wrong and how to fix those two problems.

Comment: I think your normal calculation is fine, I'm confused by your construction loops. Your createMap method only seems to create normals, which is fine, but you create a normal for (x,z) and (x+1,z+1), but you loop with (x++, z++) so the normal at (x+1,z+1) is ultimately overwritten in the next loop. You need to have 2 normals for each tile, so either create a bigger 2D array or create 2 arrays, one for the "upper" triangle and one for the "lower". I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but please clarify/modify :). The big black diagonal stripe is probably caused by your lighting settings.

Comment: I do create the tiles in my createMap method. It's the double for loop at the top. I tried creating two arrays like you said. ALso, I have found out that the "lower" triangle is always the one with the lighting problem. And the top one does fine. But on the underside of the map it's the other way around. My guess is that the normal of the lower triangle faces the wrong way? Anyway, I have uploaded my whole Map.java class. You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/Ej1pG14Y

Comment: I think the problem might be the winding of your triangles, I'm a bit cloudy now but one of your triangles seems to be counter-clock and one clock-wise. Both triangles will draw (if you disable culling) but the normal will be flipped. try reversing the order to UtilMath.getNormal(p3, p2, p1); at the lower triangle and see if it works. If it works, rewrite your code to have counter-clockwise winding of the triangles.